# Date time format jquery template

Tags: jquery, ajax, json

i have JSON data consist date like this 2013-12-25

how to format date to be 25 Dec 2013 in jquery template

here is my template

```
<td>${date_reminder1}</td>
```

Comment: why don't u pass it as date and then you can use jstl <fmt:formatDate value="${data}" pattern="yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm"/>, if not, then it's a simple string processing, just get the td with jquery and modify its text

Comment: what is jstl, i use php and javascript

Comment: see answer below, instead of alert you can put it in, or change it on document ready, but it's best to format it on your server side

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok... here you go:

assume you have < td id="testing">2013-12-25< / td>

```
    var temp = $("#testing").text();
    var split = temp.split('-');

    var year = split[0];
    var date = split[2];
    var month;
    switch(split[1]){
        case '11': month = 'Nov'; break;
        case '12': month = 'Dec';break;
        default: month = 'not found'; 
    }
    alert(year+month+date);
```